calculate optimum order quantity from supplier, based on forecasted demand python in dataframe
below are my demand forecast, based on this, i will like to determine the optimum quantity to order from my supplier.
2016-06-30    3196.276292
2016-07-31    2963.649104
2016-08-31    2695.774926
2016-09-30    2595.090061
2016-10-31    2963.573648
2016-11-30    2767.602512
2016-12-31    2947.536752
2017-01-31    2907.608736
2017-02-28    3101.192581
2017-03-31    3105.799599
2017-04-30    3192.416920
2017-05-31    3260.181956
2017-06-30    3196.769778
2017-07-31    3546.028570
2017-08-31    2854.070753
2017-09-30    3234.990407
2017-10-31    3021.252371
2017-11-30    3129.856535
2017-12-31    2967.641519
2018-01-31    3089.990677
2018-02-28    2713.715199
2018-03-31    3014.362837
2018-04-30    3219.258500
2018-05-31    3212.581639
2018-06-30    3473.809863
2018-07-31    3309.952544
2018-08-31    2991.958277
2018-09-30    2948.191574
2018-10-31    3247.865622
2018-11-30    3087.890549
2018-12-31    3227.388069
2019-01-31    3206.638691
2019-02-28    3332.874030
2019-03-31    3372.468443
2019-04-30    3473.064424
2019-05-31    3532.031586
2019-06-30    3506.986853
2019-07-31    3795.603304
2019-08-31    3147.842160
2019-09-30    3478.570494
2019-10-31    3325.509779
2019-11-30    3402.372055
2019-12-31    3275.814767
2020-01-31    3381.251904
2020-02-29    3064.365387

please find the code i used below, but i can only get results for one date displayed at a time
I will like to get out below in a dataframe format such that I have forecasted demand,optimum order quantity, reorder point, safety stocklevel
"Forecasted Demand:", forecasted_femand
"Optimal Order Quantity:", order_quantity
"Reorder Point:", reorder_point
"Safety Stock:", safety_stock

# Create date indices for the future predictions
future_steps=10
future_dates = pd.date_range(start=past_Demand.index[-1] + pd.DateOffset(days=30), periods=future_steps, freq='D')

# Create a pandas Series with the predicted values and date indices
forecasted_demand = pd.Series(predictions, index=future_dates)

# Initial inventory level
initial_inventory = 10860

# Lead time (number of days it takes to replenish inventory) 
lead_time = 10 

# Service level (probability of not stocking out)
service_level = 0.95 

# Calculate the optimal order quantity using the Newsvendor formula
z = np.abs(np.percentile(forecasted_demand, 100 * (10 - service_level)))
order_quantity = np.ceil(forecasted_demand.mean() + z).astype(int)

# Calculate the reorder point
reorder_point = forecasted_demand.mean() * lead_time + z
safety_stock = reorder_point - forecasted_demand.mean() * lead_time

print("Optimal Order Quantity:", order_quantity)
print("Reorder Point:", reorder_point)
print("Safety Stock:", safety_stock)

I am trying to get my result into a dataframe;  is there a way to get this into a dataframe format, so they are showing in the next columns to demand? the is safety stock level, reorderpoint, optimum purchase quantity each month? please any help would be most appreciated

Isn't this just a follow-up to your previous question which is still open?

yes, but beacuse I am now asking a different question, didnt know if asking it under that tread would be best. the initial one was raising error but I am now asking how to create a dataframe from the results. I am new with posting here, should i close the previous as the error issue has been resolved

If your asking how to create a dataframe from a sequence of pandas Series, read the pandas docs, and come back with a specific question if you have difficulty.
